# PostgreSQL - is there any way that I can find all of the foreign keys that reference a certain table?

Tags: postgresql

I can find all of the foreign keys belonging to a certain table pretty well using the information_schema

But I can't figure out how I can find the foreign keys from OTHER tables which reference a certain table.

All I want to know is which rows from which tables in my database are referencing the primary key of one of my tables.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT * FROM pg_constraint WHERE confrelid=<oid of destination table>
```

Or if you just want to see them interactively, they shown in the output of `\d <table name>` in `psql`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's make a few tables we can use for testing.

```
create table test (
  n integer primary key
);

-- There might be more than one schema.
create schema scratch;
create table scratch.a (
 test_n integer not null references test (n),
 incept_date date not null default current_date,
 primary key (test_n, incept_date)
);

create table b (
 test_n integer not null references test (n),
 incept_date date not null default current_date,
 primary key (test_n, incept_date)
);

-- The same table name can exist in different schemas.
create table scratch.b (
 test_n integer not null references test (n),
 incept_date date not null default current_date,
 primary key (test_n, incept_date)
);
```

I prefer to use information_schema views for this kind of stuff, because what I learn is portable to other database management systems.

I usually leave concatenation up to application programs, but I think it's 
easier to understand the output here if I concatenate columns and give them aliases. The careful programmer will use the "full name" in all the joins--catalog (database), schema, and name.

```
select distinct
    KCU2.table_catalog || '.' || KCU2.table_schema || '.' || KCU2.table_name referenced_table,
    RC.constraint_catalog || '.' || RC.constraint_schema || '.' || RC.constraint_name full_constraint_name,
    KCU1.table_catalog || '.' || KCU1.table_schema || '.' || KCU1.table_name referencing_table

from information_schema.referential_constraints RC

inner join information_schema.key_column_usage KCU1 on 
    RC.constraint_catalog = KCU1.constraint_catalog and
    RC.constraint_schema = KCU1.constraint_schema and
    RC.constraint_name = KCU1.constraint_name

inner join information_schema.key_column_usage KCU2 on
    RC.unique_constraint_catalog = KCU2.constraint_catalog and
    RC.unique_constraint_schema = KCU2.constraint_schema and
    RC.unique_constraint_name = KCU2.constraint_name

 where 
     KCU2.table_catalog = 'sandbox' and
     KCU2.table_schema = 'public' and
     KCU2.table_name = 'test'

order by referenced_table, referencing_table
;
```

```
referenced_table     full_constraint_name           referencing_table
--
sandbox.public.test  sandbox.public.b_test_n_fkey   sandbox.public.b
sandbox.public.test  sandbox.scratch.a_test_n_fkey  sandbox.scratch.a
sandbox.public.test  sandbox.scratch.b_test_n_fkey  sandbox.scratch.b
```

I think that will get you started. A foreign key doesn't have to reference a primary key; it can reference *any* candidate key. This query tells you which tables have a foreign key to our test table, sandbox.public.test, which seems to be what you're looking for.